# What is the proper way of setting the page title in CakePHP 2.6?

Tags: cakephp, seo, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I am new to Cakephp and searching for how to set page titles and meta keywords,desc. for best SEO management.

I have checked any tutorials and question , I would like to ask that is it necessary to set up title in controller page and then fetch in any page of VIEW/mypage?

I am trying to set direct title in my home page in a way like :

```
$this->set('title', 'My Page Title');
```

But this is not working , Is there any way to direct set title without connection with controller?

I am using Version **2.6.3** of CakePhp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CakePHP 2.5, the right way of setting the **title** is as follows:

In your layout:

```
$this->fetch('title')
```

In you view:

```
$this->assign('title', 'My Page Title')
```

The same applies to the **meta tags**:

In your layout:

```
<? echo $this->Html->meta('keywords',$this->fetch('keywords'));?>
<? echo $this->Html->meta('description',$this->fetch('description'));?>
```

In you view:

```
<? $this->assign('keywords', 'My meta tags')?>
<? $this->assign('description', 'My description')?>
```

More on [CakePHP Layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts).

Comment: Thanks I will try same and let you know.

Comment: Title is working but meta is not working , it is printing meta tags at top of page instead of consider as meta tags.

Comment: You have to wrap it in `$this->Html->meta()`. I've edited the post.

Comment: If I do not have same page in View and layout , and if page is only in View then how can I set directly title?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Every view is wrapped in a layout, and printed where  `<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>` is located inside the layout.

Comment: Actually in my site I can see that home.ctp file is there in folder  **View**, but in layout there is no connection or page available related to home , so how can I set title for home page?

Comment: It defaults to app/View/Layouts/default.ctp. You only need one layout file, but can have more if required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97077/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-inigo-flores).

Answer (score 0):

The title tag would be set in the default.ctp of the layout in use, e.g. `app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`. You can hardcode your values there.

The displayed value comes from the `PagesController::display()` (`app/Controller/PagesController.php`), generated from the directory the rendered view resides in.

Setting your SEO title in a controller `$this->set('seotitel', 'Foo')` should propagate the value to the `default.ctp`, where you can display it:

```
<title>
    <?php echo $seotitel ?>
</title>
```

N.B. this is untested due to lack of a running 2.6 instance.

Comment: Thanks I will try same and let you know.